# What is the use and motivation for this particular concept in permutations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Say you have the permutation $(54231)$ element of $S_5$

Now you drop say the "4" and then re-rank the remnant permutation on the other elements.

Then you are left with,  $(4231)$ element of $S_4$

Anyone has seen this operation and has any insights about this?
Is this known by some name? 
Why is this an useful idea?

---

Also note this related article: 
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Derived_permutation

Comment: This is basically building the permutation $\tau_{\pi(n),n}\pi$ (wich fixes $n$) and then restricting this to $S_{n-1}$... What's so special about it?

Comment: I am asking as to what we know about such things. Like is my example exactly the same as what the link calls as "derived permutation"? Where do these constructions appear? Like any natural setting for this peculiar non-canonical map from $S_n$ to $S_{n-1}$?

Comment: Yes, your definition coincides with the article. I don't know anything fancy about those, though. Do you have a specific setting in mind?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a particularly natural thing to do. Among other things, it's not a group homomorphism.

Comment: Well - I am thinking of it this way - (1) What is a good description of such maps from S_n to S_{n-1}? Any classification known about them? (2) Any natural setting where this is useful? (3)  Like there are lots of elements inside $S_n$ which on such a fixing operation would go down to the same element of $S_{n-1}$. Any understanding exists about these?

Comment: Yes. Believe it or not this is my research. I'm on a cell phone now but I'll write an answer later.

Comment: Great! :) I am waiting to hear back from you!

Answer (score 3):

These are called permutation patterns. The smaller permutation you obtain is called the pattern. It is usually considered as a subsequence of the permutation, and we say that the permutation "contains" the pattern, and if it does not contain the pattern then it "avoids" it. Thus $54231$ contains the pattern $4231$ at positions $1,3,4,5$, but it avoids the pattern $3412$.

As simple as this is, this is very deep. Though it of course wasn't always thought of this way, this is a Coxeter group thing, which means it has combinatorial, geometric, and algebraic aspects to it.

For the combinatorial aspect, see the Wikipedia article on permutation patterns. This is not my specialty but that article seems to have a lot of info.

For the geometry, permutation patterns allow one to determine certain properties of Schubert varieties in homogeneous spaces of complex semisimple linear algebraic groups (see the Wikipedia article on Schubert calculus). Schubert varieties in a flag variety of type $A$ are indexed by permutations, and, for example, a Schubert variety is smooth if and only if its permutation avoids the patterns $4231$ and $3412$. I was able to prove that rational smoothness/smoothness of Schubert varieties in generalized flag varieties (possibly infinite-dimensional) is a pattern avoidance property, meaning that if a Schubert variety is (rationally) smooth, then a Schubert variety corresponding to any pattern the element contains is also (rationally) smooth. (This was proved for finite-dimensional flag varieties by Billey and Postnikov.) It was never published.

Algebraically, these kind of maps are homomorphisms of weak order and can be easily classified. I will now present the situation in ridiculous generality, but you have to promise not to laugh. The following was going to be the basis of my dissertation but I ended up doing something else instead.

A Coxeter system is a pair $(W,S)$ where $W$ is a group and $S$ is a generating set such that $W$ has a presentation involving only the relations $s^2=1$ for all $s\in S$ as well as zero or more relations of the form $(ss')^m=1$ for $s,s'\in S$ and some integer $m\geq 2$ depending on $s,s'$. Patterns arise from group homomorphisms that are easiest to describe in terms of abstract root systems.

$W$ has a length function $\ell$ sending an element to the smallest number of elements of $S$ required to express it as a product. Let $T$ be the set of elements conjugate to some element of $S$ (which are all of order 2) and let $R=T\times \{-1,1\}$. Elements of $R$ will be called roots, elements of $T\times \{1\}$ positive roots, and elements of $T\times \{-1\}$ negative roots.

We define a (nonassociative) product $\ast$ on $R$ by the rule
$$(t,e)\ast (t',e')=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}(tt't,e')&\mbox{ if }\ell(tt')>\ell(t)\\
(tt't,-e')&\mbox{ otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$
This product extends to an action of $W$ on $R$ such that
$$w\ast (t',e')=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}(wt'w^{-1},e')&\mbox{ if }\ell(wt')>\ell(w)\\
(wt'w^{-1},-e')&\mbox{ otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

The set 
$$I(w)=\{(t,1):\ell(wt)<\ell(w)\}$$
is called the inversion set of $w$ and completely characterizes $w$. If $R,R'$ are root systems of the Coxeter systems $(W,S),(W',S')$ then a function $f:R\to R'$ such that 
$$f(r\ast r')=f(r)\ast f(r')$$
such that $f(r)$ is positive whenever $r$ is positive is called a homomorphism of root systems. The *pattern map* $f^{\ast}:W'\to W$ is the function such that $f^{\ast}(w')=w$, where $w$ is the unique element such that
$$I(w)=f^{-1}(I(w'))$$

For $W=S_n$ we have that $S$ consists of the adjacent transpositions $(i,i+1)$ and $T$ consists of all transpositions. There are two kinds of homomorphism $R_m\to R_n$ (where $R_i$ is the abstract root system corresponding to $S_i$): ones where there is a sequence $1\leq a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_m\leq n$ such that $f((i,j),e)=((a_i,a_j),e)$, thus embedding the smaller permutation into a larger permutation, and ones where the sequence of $a_i$ is decreasing instead. These are equivalent up to automorphism. For the increasing homomorphisms, the pattern map is exactly the construction you describe, deleting multiple indices at a time, leaving the flattened permutation at $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m$ behind.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! But 54231 contains the pattern 4231 even at positions 4,2,3,1 - right?

Comment: It contains it at 1,3,4,5 and 2,3,4,5.

Comment: In the permutation "54231", if one removes the "2" then one is left with "5431" and this after re-ranking is the permutation "4321" and NOT the permutation "4231". So I am not getting your argument about what you mean if you say that "54231 contains the permutation 4231 at positions 1,3,4,5"

Comment: They are the list of indices. 1,3,4,5 means you exclude the element in the second *position*, not the 2.

Comment: Is this removal and re-ranking correspond to some operation at the level of the permutation matrices? Do we know when can two permutations become equal after a removal and re-ranking?

Comment: I don't understand your question about matrices, but which permutations are sent to the same one is a combinatorial problem. If the indices are not fixed it is a very hard question to answer and is essentially the whole combinatorial aspect of the field. If they are fixed then you pick a set of numbers to make the pattern of length $m$, which you can do $\binom n m$ ways, then permute the remaining elements arbitrarily, which you can do $(n-m)!$ ways, so the number of permutations sent to the same one is $n!/m!$, so they are evenly distributed.

Comment: The same is true for general Coxeter groups, as there is exactly one representative of each pattern in each coset of the image of the induced group homomorphism.

Comment: @MattSamuel Think of being given two permutations $\pi_1, \pi_2 \in S_n$, I am asking if there is any "iff" criteria when there will exists a removal and re-ranking choice for each of them such that both collapse to the same permutation in $S_{n-1}$?

Comment: @Anirbit a nontrivial characterization depends entirely on the particular permutation in $S_{n-1}$. There's no easy answer to that. That's why this is so deep.

Comment: What do you mean by "depends on particular permutation of S_{n-1}"? Say I give you two permutations of $S_n$ and ask if there exists a removal and reranking process which collapse them to the same element of $S_{n-1}$. Are you saying that the only way to answer this question is basically to try all the $2n$ possible options ? ($n$ options for each permutation)

Comment: @Anirbit I don't know of any genetic better way.

Comment: Interesting! I was thinking of a question of this kind "What is the largest possible subset of S_n such that for no pair of them does there exists a choice of removal and re-ranking which will collapse them into the same element of S_{n-1}?$